# Exporting an ImageCollection using Service Account

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google-earth-engine-python-api

When exporting an image to an ImageCollection using a serviceaccount to a legacy project, e.g.
`ee.Export.toAsset(myImage, "description", "projects/earthengine-legacy/assets/projects/myproject/collection")`
I get an error: `Insufficient permissions to create asset 'projects/earthengine-legacy/assets/projects/myproject/collection'`. I did give my serviceaccount `writer` permission on the ImageCollection.
When exporting to a non-legacy cloud asset, I can export normally (e.g. `projects/<<cloud-project>>/collection`).

Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who may stumble upon this, exporting map tiles to a bucket requires owner permissions. Setting `writePublicTiles` to `False` (`ee.batch.Export.map.toCloudStorage`) resolves the issue.

Comment: I use service accounts time to time, haven't faced this yet but  I'll keep this in mind. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The 'writer' permission doesn't do anything for legacy projects, sadly. Just use Cloud project when you need multiple accounts.